# Creating Multiple folders using CMD commands in a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a backup folder that contains sub folders of all the months of the year 2016 and those  subfolders with sub folders of all the days in each month. I'd like to use a bat file to do this.
The best I could do is this.

```
md "E:\cctv backup"
cd "E:\cctv backup"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016"
cd "E:\cctv backup\October 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\01 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\02 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\03 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\04 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\05 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\06 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\06 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\08 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\09 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\10 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\11 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\12 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\13 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\14 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\15 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\16 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\17 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\18 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\19 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\20 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\21 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\22 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\23 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\24 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\25 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\26 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\27 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\28 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\29 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\30 Oct 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\October 2016\31 Oct 2016"
cd "E:\cctv backup\November 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\01 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\02 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\03 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\04 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\05 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\06 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\07 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\08 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\09 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\10 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\11 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\12 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\13 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\14 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\15 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\16 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\17 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\18 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\19 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\20 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\21 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\22 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\23 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\24 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\25 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\26 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\27 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\28 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\29 Nov 2016"
md "E:\cctv backup\November 2016\30 Nov 2016"
```

Comment: If your code works but you just want to make it smaller (and you definitely can), you may want to ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You don't need to create any parent directories. The command `md one\two\three` will create directories one and two if they don't exist. Also, use `for /l` command (type `for /?` for help) to iterate through days in the month (but remember 31 vs 30).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot..the for command is the one am actually struggling with. How do I iterate through the days of the month at the same time creating them as sub folders in the month parent folders.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /L %%y IN (2015,1,2017) DO (
 FOR %%m IN (January,February,March,April,May,June,
             July,August,September,October,November,December) DO (
   SET "monabbr=%%m"
   SET "monabbr=!monabbr:~0,3!"
   SET /a maxday=131
   IF "!monabbr!"=="Apr" SET /a maxday=130
   IF "!monabbr!"=="Jun" SET /a maxday=130
   IF "!monabbr!"=="Sep" SET /a maxday=130
   IF "!monabbr!"=="Nov" SET /a maxday=130
   IF "!monabbr!"=="Feb" (
    SET /a maxday=128
    SET /a leap=%%y %% 4
    IF !leap!==0 SET /a maxday=129
   )
   FOR /L %%d IN (101,1,!maxday!) DO (
    SET "daynum=%%d"
    SET "daynum=!daynum:~-2!"
    ECHO(MD "%targetdir%\%%m %%y\!daynum! !monabbr! %%y"

   )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The start, step and end years are obvious - in `%%y`

Then, for each full-monthname in `%%m`, select the first 3 letters into `monabbr` using `delayedexpansion` and substringing, then calculate the maximum days in a month, normally 131 except if the month abbreviations indicate 30, and February - see whether it's a leap-year and select 28 or 29. Add 100 to this maximum so that the start, step, end yield a 3-digit day number in `%%d`, then calculate the last 2 digits of that day number to `daynum`, and bang the elements together in the appropriate order to create the required lowest-level subdirectory, remembering that this will also create any intermediate directories required.

Comment: Hey so I ran your script but it's not giving any output. Is there something am doing wrong. I changed echo(md to md. But still nothing.

Comment: Well - it works perfectly for me. You'd need to provide more information about what happened. The code is quite sensitive to layout so cutting-and-pasting rather than attempting to retype is advisable - and use a proper editor line EDITPLUS, not WORD or any WP application. If you insert a `echo %%x` in the line directly after `for %%x...` (where `x` may be `y`, `m` or `d`) - that might reveal some pertinent issue.